# For which pairs $(a/b)$ is $f(a,b)$ defined?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Suppose, $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers.

Dirichlet's theorem states that infinite many primes of the form $an+b$ exist, if $n$ runs over the positive integers.

Let $p_1,p_2,\cdots $ be the sequence of those primes in increasing order ($b$ does not count, if it is prime, because we assume $n>0$) and denote $$s_k:=\sum_{j=1}^k p_j$$

Now, define $f(a,b)=m$ as the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $s_m$ is a perfect square. If no such $m$ exists, then $f(a,b)$ should be undefined.

In other words, we sum up the primes of the form $an+b$ in increasing order and stop as soon as the sum is a perfect square. In this case , $f(a,b)$ is the number of primes we must sum up. If we never get a perfect square, $f(a,b)$ is not defined.

> Can we decide for which pairs $(a/b)$ , $f(a,b)$ is defined ?

In the range $1\le a,b\le 10$, I noticed the following hard cases :

```
[8, 1]
[8, 7]
[8, 9]
[9, 1]
[9, 2]
[9, 7]
[9, 8]
[9, 10]
```

Is $f(a,b)$ defined for those pairs ?

Comment: The sequence for $[9,2]$ resolves at prime $1623391607$ when the sum is $103011660^2$.

Comment: Note, that:

 - $[8,1],[8,9]\to[8,17]$ run for primes under 1 billion if my paridroid didn't lie, no cases up to that work. 
 - $[9,1],[9,10]\to[9,19]\to[18,19]$ primes under 1 billion tested
 - [$9,8]\to[9,17]\to[18,17]$ now also tested to 1 billion, no cases found. 

By trying to keep values low yet duplicating, you are trying way more cases than needed. Another thing to note is $k$ can only be in certain equivalence class mod the modulus. For the 19 mod 18 case, these values are 0,1,4,9,16,7,13,10 mod 18. the 17 mod 18 case is 0,17,14,9,2,11,5,8 mod 18.

Comment: Sum for $[9,7]$ up to prime $3866932177$ is $240389025^2$. Sum for $[9,1]$ (and $[9,10]$) up to prime $4137295501$ is $256787671^2$. None of the other listed cases terminate at a prime below $10^{11}$. Found using PARI/GP with an algorithm that iterates over the primes and maintains all sums in parallel.

Comment: I was simply using forprimestep when I did mine.